# How to call the ItestResult methode from the another class?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects, selenium-extent-report

I have two classes, I want to call the public void getResult(ITestResult result) method of class "A" in class "B" how to call it? I am getting the NullPointerException

First Class

```
public class loginPage{

public WebDriver driver;
Utility ut= new Utility();
ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
 ExtentReports extent;
 ExtentTest logger;
By EmailId= By.xpath("//*[@name='Email']");
By password = By.xpath("//*[@name='Password']");
By LoginBtn= By.xpath("//*[@id='frmLogIn']/div[4]/button");


public loginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver=driver;

}


 @BeforeTest
    public void startReport(){

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/ExtentReport.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports ();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "SoftwareTestingMaterial");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "Automation Testing");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Rajkumar SM");

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Title of the Report Comes here");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Name of the Report Comes here");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    }
 @Test
public void setusername(WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(EmailId).sendKeys("nilima@mailinator.com");
        logger = extent.createTest("setusername");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case Passed is setusername", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Time out exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setusername");
    } 
    catch (ElementNotSelectableException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not selectable exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setusername");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No such element found " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setusername");
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setusername");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something Wrong" + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setusername");

    }

}
@Test
public void setpassword(WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(password).sendKeys("123123");
        logger = extent.createTest("setpassword");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case Passed is setpassword", ExtentColor.GREEN));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Time out exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setpassword");
    } 
    catch (ElementNotSelectableException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not selectable exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setpassword");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No such element found " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setpassword");
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setpassword");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something Wrong" + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "setpassword");
    }

}

@Test
public void Login()
{
    try
    {
        driver.findElement(LoginBtn).click();
        String Title="Login | ORGCAP";
        String GetTitle = driver.getTitle();
        logger = extent.createTest("Login");
        Assert.assertEquals(Title, GetTitle);
        logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case Passed is Login", ExtentColor.GREEN));

    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Time out exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Login");
    } 
    catch (ElementNotSelectableException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not selectable exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Login");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No such element found " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Login");
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Login");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something Wrong" + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Login");
    }
}


    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result){
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        }else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
            logger.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Skipped", ExtentColor.ORANGE));   
        }
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void endReport(){
        extent.flush();
    }
```

}

My Second class is

```
 public class login extends TestBuild{
 ITestResult result;

@Test()
public void Loginadmin() throws IOException{

    TestBuild BrowserSetUp= new TestBuild();
    BrowserSetUp.setup();
    loginPage lp= new loginPage(driver);
    lp.startReport();
    lp.setusername(driver);
    lp.setpassword(driver);
    lp.Login();
    lp.getResult(result);
    lp.endReport();
}
}
```

I am getting NullPointerException at:

> if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) line.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend the base class where you have written the ITestResult method. e.g.

```
public class BusinessGroup_Add extends CallAllFunctions{
WebDriver driver;
Company_Add company= new Company_Add(driver);
Utility ut= new Utility();


By BG_Menu=By.xpath("//*[@id='mainnav-menu']/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a");
By Open_BG_form= By.xpath("//*[@id='page-title']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/a/i");
By BG_Name=By.name("Name");
By CountryDropDown= By.xpath("//*[@id='countryDiv']/div/a/span");
By AllCountry= By.xpath("//*[@id='countryDiv']/div/div/ul");
By StateDropdown= By.xpath("//*[@id='stateDiv']/div/a/span");
By AllState= By.xpath("//*[@id='stateDiv']/div/div/ul/li");
By Location= By.xpath("//*[@id='cityDiv']/div/a/span");
By AllLocation= By.xpath("//*[@id='cityDiv']/div/div/ul/li");
By Description= By.xpath("//*[@id='locModel']/div[6]/textarea");
By save= By.id("businessGrpSubmit");
By CancleSave= By.xpath("//*[@id='frmBusinessGrp']/div[4]/button[2]");

By ModalTitle=By.xpath("//*[@id='frmBusinessGrp']/div[1]/h4");
public BusinessGroup_Add(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver=driver;
}

public void Click_BG(WebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        Boolean staleElement = true; 
        while(staleElement){
          try{
              WebElement BGMenubar=driver.findElement(BG_Menu);
              Boolean dropdownPresent =BGMenubar.isDisplayed();

                if(dropdownPresent==true)
                {
                    WebElement ele=(WebElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(BG_Menu));

                    ele.click();
                    test = extent.createTest("Navigate to BG");
                    String Actual=driver.findElement(company.PageHeader).getText();
                    String expcted="Business Group";
                    Assert.assertEquals(Actual, expcted);
                    test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Navigate to BG successfully", ExtentColor.GREEN));

                }
                else{
                    WebElement master1= (WebElement) new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(company.master));

                    master1.click();

                    WebElement ele=(WebElement) new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(BG_Menu));
                    ele.click();
                    test = extent.createTest("Navigate to BG");
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    String Actual=driver.findElement(company.PageHeader).getText();
                    System.out.println("Dashboard prnted+++++++++"+Actual);
                    String expcted="Business Group";
                    Assert.assertEquals(Actual, expcted);
                    test.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Navigate to BG successfully", ExtentColor.GREEN));
                }
             staleElement = false;

          } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
            staleElement = true;
          }
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Time out exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Click_BG");
    } 
    catch (ElementNotSelectableException e) {
        System.out.println("Element not selectable exception " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Click_BG");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("No such element found " + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Click_BG");
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Click_BG");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something Wrong" + e);
        ut.capturescreenshot(driver, "Click_BG");
    }



}
```

you will get your result in base class

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exception, because the object result of ITestResult you are passing has no value. It get value in @AfterMethod annotation.

There are basically two ways, by achieve this:

1. You can create BaseClass which has Common Configuration methods, and by creating objects of the class you can call those methods into your annotations.
2. You can create BaseClass which has common configuration methods with TestNG annotations, and in your every test you just have to manage your @Test only. No need to maintain annotations in each individual Test(Its applicable if you have extended BaseClass) in every test.

Let me share example, which has similar concept. [Click Here](https://github.com/ishah09/Selenium-JavaDemos/tree/master/src/test/java/SuiteStructure)